# When inlining a subclass constructor, does it also inline the superclass constructor?

Tags: c++

In C++, inline is in the compilation phase, while construction and destruction are in the runtime phase. So if the constructor of a subclass is inlined, will the constructor of the parent class also be inlined when the constructor of the subclass is called? Hou Jie's book recommends that construction and destruction not be inline because they call functions of the parent class, making the code more complex than it seems.

Comment: `inline` usually have 2 meanings. Which one are you talking about? The question is not clear.

Comment: *"inline is in the compilation phase, while construction and destruction are in the runtime phase"* -- You're comparing apples and oranges. Whether or not a function is inlined by the compiler occurs during compilation, yes. The function is run at runtime, yes. (Constructors are "just" special functions as far as this question goes.) What's your point? This distinction does not seem to have any bearing on the rest of your question *(unless you are talking about the `inline` keyword, I guess, but that occurs during coding time)*.

Comment: the term "inline" is rather overloaded in c++, thats why you should include an example with some code

Comment: Hou Jie's advice is wrong. The compiler decides what is inlined, not the programmer. It's seems this author is confusing inlining during code generation with the inlining as it applies to the one definition rule (ODR). This is a common beginner misunderstanding but it's disappointing to hear a book author make the same mistake.

Comment: If the compiler inlines one function, there is no rule that it also has to inline any functions called from the first function.

Comment: As compilers get improved actual meaning of `inline` has been changed. Now it means "if you see multiple definition of a function do not threat this as an error". It doesn't have impact if function will be inline in machine code or not. Very very old compilers were using this as a hint that function code should be placed where it is used.

Answer (score 0):

Look at some examples:

```cpp
struct base {
    base();
};

struct derived : base {
    derived() : base() { /*...*/ }
};

derived d;
```

`derived::derived()` might be inlined when constructing `d`, but the base class's constructor can't be inlined since the definition is not available.

In this case, the inlining turns the code to construct `d` from "call `derived::derived()`" to "call `base::base()`; code for `/*...*/`".

---

```cpp
// header file
struct base {
    base() { /*...*/ }
};
struct derived : base {
    derived();
};
inline derived d;
```

```cpp
// source file
derived::derived() : base() { /*...*/ }
```

Here, the derived class's constructor can't be inlined in the header file because the definition isn't available (depending on link time optimization). The base class's constructor *can* be inlined into the derived class's constructor since the definition is available.

---

Remember that a constructor will call the constructors for base classes in sequence, then constructors for members in sequence, then run the constructor bodies. These individual parts can be inlined like any other function call.